# WordPress Remove Menu Pages Except for Super Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a snippet to remove some WordPress menu pages.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'notadmin_remove_menus', 999 ); 
function notadmin_remove_menus() {
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');
    remove_menu_page('jetpack');
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=featured_item');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=feedback');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=blocks');
}
```

The problem is this code also remove menu pages for super admin. I want to remove these menu for all users except super admin. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'notadmin_remove_menus', 999 ); 
function notadmin_remove_menus() {
    if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
        remove_menu_page('edit.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
        remove_menu_page('upload.php');
        remove_menu_page('jetpack');
        remove_menu_page('users.php');
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=featured_item');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=feedback');
        remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=blocks');
    }
}
```

or

```
if ( !is_super_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'notadmin_remove_menus', 999 ); 
}


function notadmin_remove_menus() {

    remove_menu_page('edit.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');
    remove_menu_page('jetpack');
    remove_menu_page('users.php');
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=featured_item');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=feedback');
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=blocks');

}
```